# Change Dateformat in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I want to change the date-format in the view. I am passing an array to the view from the controller.
Right now date which is echo is `YYYY-DD-MM` that is `2014-03-12` (this format is save in the MYSQL). But, I want this date to be change to the `MM/DD/YY` format e.g: `03/12/14`

View.php

```
foreach($accounts as $row){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row->id_job."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row->date_of_plans."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: There are a few date time functions available.  http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date("m/d/y", strtotime($row->date_of_plans))
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
foreach($accounts as $row){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row->id_job."</td>";
    echo "<td>".date('m/d/Y',strtotime($row->date of plans))."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct, but can tick one at a time.